# Simple image change

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

I have a large image which is basically a project cover photo and underneath it I have five thumbnail images.

I want to make it so that when you click on a thumbnail the large image will change to correspond with the thumbnail that was clicked.

I'm not sure what this is called so I have been having trouble researching it.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

It's called an image gallery/slider. You usually need javascript/jQuery to implement it.

Here are some [examples and tutorials](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/)

Comment: Great thanks! I wasn't sure if it was called a slider because nothing is moving.

Comment: @Downvoter why are you downvoting?

Comment: @ncuda You are welcome. Yes actually I would define what you want as an image gallery, but most image sliders can be configured to work in the way of a gallery (per click). ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this will give you an overall idea of how to implement it

```
<div class="gallery">

    <div id="mainViewport" class="viewport">
        <img src="my-picture.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>

    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li><img src="imgs/my-picture-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li><img src="imgs/my-picture2-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li><img src="imgs/my-picture3-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>
    var mainViewport = $('#mainViewport');
    $('.thumbnails img').click(function(){
        var path = $(this).attr('src').replace('-thumbnail','');
        var mainImg = new Image();
        mainImg.src = path;
        mainViewport.html(mainImg);

    });   
</script>
```

Now you need to store your thumbnails in this format, 'path/to/full/img-thumbnail.jpg' so you will be adding '-thumbnail' for the smaller versions, and in the script you remove that part to get the full sized img path and place and replace the current img in the mainViewport div.

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wbT4N/1/

Please be aware that i do not have a thumbnail version and a fullversion of this pictures, i just placed some dummy .jpg , you should have both, and name the as i explained.

Good luck